# How to find nth palindrome number using if-else where n < 100

Tags: palindrome

How can I find nth palindrome number using if-else where n < 100.Is there any way to do it in O(1)?

Comment: Assuming it's above 10 then yes. The only palindrome numbers under 100 are 11, 22, etc. So take the ```value``` and repeat it for the palindrome number. e.g 6th == 66

Comment: n is the input and I have to find nth palindrome.like what is the 100th palimdrome number?
and 6th palindrome number is 6